# Only ten records displayed in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Need to get all records (Logs) in Elasticsearch (for now, only 10 records are  showing ). but all are getting in Console. I am using Grox command for matching logs

Comment: all from all the indexes? or from a specific..from all time..? what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Shiva, can you please add more details on what query you are running, what is your TYPE  and documents look like.

Comment: You're probably missing the [`size`parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html) in your query.

Comment: By default, elasticsearch queries return only 10 results. Which would explain why you are getting this result. In order to see more results, you'll have to use the size parameter, as proposed by Val. Or you could install Kibana and connect it to elasticsearch for easy browsing.